# Change figurename size in appendix

Tags: macros, xetex

Good day,

I have to change the font size of a figurename (and  caption) in my appendix. Trying this one:

```
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\appendix}
  {%
   % another commands...
   \g@addto@macro\appendix{\renewcommand{\thefigurename}{\large \thefigurename \normalsize}}
   %...
  }
\makeatother
```

Comment: What is the question? Does your approach not work? What is the rest of your document, which document class do you use, which packages enter the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{\let\oldfigurename\figurename
\renewcommand{\figurename}{\large \oldfigurename}}
\makeatletter
```

or

```
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\appendix}
  {%
   % another commands...
   \let\oldfigurename\figurename
   \renewcommand{\figurename}{\large \oldfigurename}
   %...
  }
\makeatother
```

**Notes**

there is no command `\thefigurename`

Don't use `\g@addto@macro\appendix`inside `\appendix`

Comment: Shouldn't you store `\appendix` as well and, say, to `\oldappendix` and use it in the redefinition of `\appendix` in the second example? (which, by the way, does not need the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair (as it stands)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't think so, since we don't know what  the OP  really need to do with it.

Comment: True, the question is unclear, but as it stands your redefinition of `\appendix` does only redefine `\figurename` but any other feature of `\appendix` vanished...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i suppose `% another commands...` and   `%...` before and after `\figurename` redefinition mean some thing (less inportant here) in the redefinition of `\appendix`. In  other words i just correct the OP's code.

Comment: Alright ... I think, you got more feedback from me than from the O.P. (and the upvote is mine :-P)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer did i say that  i trust you? ;-)

Comment: `\let\oldfigurename\figurename\renewcommand{\figurename}{\large \oldfigurename}` solved my problem. There is a lot of redefenition in the `\renewcommand{appendix}{...}`. Yes, you are right, I want `\large` figurename in my appendix and `\normalsize` in another one.